# jQuery extract page number in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to get the last occurrence of the page number in the URL using the either a regex or string manipulation.

www.somedomain.com/about-us/meet-the-team/**4**/

www.somedomain.com/about-us/meet-the-team/7/section/**4**/

www.somedomain.com/about-us/meet-the-team/**4**/?val1=somevalue&val2=somevalue

I have tried `.replace(/\/\d\//)`

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Comment: Why haven't you tried anything?

Comment: @nicael I have tried many things, otherwise, I would not be asking the question but not sure why that matters. I believe I stated the problem clearly.

Comment: Though I can't see any attempts of yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way but here is one:

```
var str = 'www.somedomain.com/about-us/meet-the-team/7/section/4/?val1=somevalue&val2=somevalue'
var match = str.match(/\/(\d+)(?!.*\/\d+)/);
alert(match[1]);
```

Summary of the regex:

- `\/(\d+)` Matches a digit (which occurs 1 or more times) after a `/` and save the digit an a capture group
- `(?!.*\/\d+)` do a negative lookahead to make sure the same pattern is not matched again after any characters.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/b0nsLv99/4/)

[Description of Regex](https://regex101.com/r/vT8nH0/1)

Comment: That works great. Is there a way to only get the last occurrence in this example. www.somedomain.com/about-us/meet-the-team/7/section/4/. So, only the 4 NOT the 7 is captured?